# How to use the same code for multiple pages that require different variables

Tags: php, html

On my website, I have partners pages, each of which contains a PHP block defining array variables which are then passed to a loop that renders the content of the page. For example, for the hotels.php page, the PHP block is the following:

```html
<?php
    $hotels = [
        ["href" => "link1", 
         "src" => "src1", 
         "alt" => "alt1", 
         "name" => "name1"
        ],
        ["href" => "link2", 
         "src" => "src2", 
         "alt" => "alt2", 
         "name" => "name2"
        ],
        ...
    ];
?>
```

Each group of partners page has a seperate php block. Since the code of each page is pretty much the same, with only difference being the PHP blocks and the way I refer to the variables ($hotels, $restaurants, etc.) I would like to merge them into one. I would merge the PHP into one and then use the URL to find out which pages I am on and figure out which variable to use to render the page.

I could do that, the problem is that if I am visiting the hotels' page, for example, I would only be using the $hotel variable and the other ones for the different types of partners would be declared but not used.

I would like to ask if the presence of unused variables would slow down the website and if there is a way of avoiding that problem (for example making the php code lazy - variables being declared only when they are called).

Comment: What about a class with `static` variables?

Comment: @NVRM What about it?

Answer (score 1):

Make a *template* like this:

*template.php*

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($entities as $entity): ?>
        <li><?= htmlspecialchars($entity['name']); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Then on your individual pages, define different `$entities` and *include the reusable template*:

*hotels.php*:

```
<?php

$entities = [...];
require 'template.php';
```